# Apply CA root certificates inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ssl, curl

How would I download the certificate (and automatically update it) within a Docker container?

Inside my Docker container which was based on Alpine, I do the following:

```
curl -I https://gtp.nlgworldwide.com
```

But I get this error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I presume I need to do something like this inside my `Dockerfile` :

```
RUN curl -s -O https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem && mv cacert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

But I am still unable to connect to the above website, so how would I ensure I get the correct CA root certificate for that website?

Comment: I meant `https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` - I've updated it

Comment: Updated it again to replace the `wget` call with `curl` but the issue seems to be related to one of the COMODO TLS CA Root certificates not being added to the certificate store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That HTTPS site causes problem for me too, using an up-to-date CA store.

The problem is that an *intermediate* COMODO cert isn't provided by the server, which is a server misconfiguration.

You **can** fix this, if you want to, by manually downloading the missing certificate and adding that to your CA store.

[The SSL Labs test verifies this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=gtp.nlgworldwide.com&latest).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I can confirm that downloading the certificate from https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/970/108/intermediate-2-sha-2-comodo-rsa-domain-validation-secure-server-ca and moving the file to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/. directory then running: "update-ca-certificates" works for me.

Comment: I have also informed the developers of the website to check with their server administrator to fix the configuration of their SSL setup but since I'm not sure how long that will take, my Dockerfile RUN/COPY commands should work in the meantime. Thanks again!